# Linear transformation when solving ODE seems too good to be true

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, initial-value-problems

I'm solving the ODE
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\beta\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2+\omega_0^2x=0,
\end{align}
with initial conditions $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(t_0)=\dot{x}_0=v_0$.

I start with the substitution
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}&=v\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}&=v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x},
\end{align}
so the ode becomes
\begin{align}
v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}+\beta v^2+\omega_0^2x=0.
\end{align}
Using an integrating factor of $2e^{2\beta x}$ I arrive at
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(v^2e^{2\beta x})+2\omega_0^2xe^{2\beta x}=0.
\end{align}
I've used definite integrals, which makes the constants messier but is where my question lies,
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^x\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(v^2e^{2\beta x})+2\omega_0^2xe^{2\beta x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{x_0}^x0\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align}
yielding
\begin{align}
v^2e^{2\beta x}+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}xe^{2\beta x}-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}e^{2\beta x}=v_0^2e^{2\beta x_0}+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}x_0e^{2\beta x_0}-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}e^{2\beta x_0}.
\end{align}
Multiplying by $e^{2\beta x}$ and solving for $v^2$ gives
\begin{align}
v^2=\left(\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}-\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}x\right)+\left(v_0^2+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}x_0-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}\right)e^{2\beta(x_0-x)}=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2.
\end{align}
This is quite messy but it is separable. That being the case I can't integrate it, and neither can <integral-calculator.com>.

That being so, if the term in front of the exponential term is zero, it is an easy solve. Simply requiring that the initial conditions satisfy that reduces this to a particular solution, but can't I just make the transformation from $x\rightarrow x'$ such that
\begin{align}
v_0'^{2}+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}x'_0-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}=0?
\end{align}
This would simply be a translation of $x$, as $x'_0$ is still a constant.

I'm asking because it seems too easy to be true, which in my experience of solving ODE's always has meant I was making an error. As well as the only way of making this transformation that I can think of is by letting
\begin{align}
v'^{2}+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\beta}x'-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2\beta^2}=0,
\end{align}
which is obviously not a valid assumption, as it necessitates $x$ be a certain function of $t$. So what I'm after is what I'm doing wrong and why I can't do that, or how to go about this transformation if it is indeed 'math legal'.

Edit:

Realized that I just need make the transformation $x=x'+A$, then solve for an $A$ that satisfies the reduction that I want. My question about this being seemingly too good still stands.

Comment: Looks like a legit step to me...  But you're right, I wonder if I too am missing something.

Comment: You are looking for solutions to the original differential equation. Quite obviously if $\omega_0 \ne 0$, adding $A\ne 0$ to a solution of that equation does not give you another solution (even allowing different initial conditions).